# How to print the logged in user name on Woocommerce My Account page?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm struggling with printing the logged in user name on the My Account page of Woocommerce. I have a function that looks like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', function() {
    _e('<p class="you-ordered">Hey! Here\'s what you ordered:</div></p>');
} );
```

I'm trying to get it to say: "Hey, Jim! Here's what you ordered:".

I've tried:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', function() {
    _e('<p class="you-ordered">Hey! '.$current_user->display_name.' Here\'s what you ordered:</div></p>');
} );
```

But that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Before the `add_action` line, try adding this:
`global $current_user;`
`get_currentuserinfo();`

Comment: So something like this? ```global $current_user; get_currentuserinfo();
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', function() {
    _e('<p class="you-ordered">Hey! '.$order->display_name.' Here\'s what you ordered:</div></p>');
} );```

Comment: In your sample, you used `$order->display_name` try `$current_user->display_name` first. If that doesn't go, try this:
`add_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', function() {   $current_user = wp_get_current_user();  _e('<p class="you-ordered">Hey! '.$current_user->display_name.' Here\'s what you ordered:</div></p>'); } );  `

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked.

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. I posted the comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_before_order_table_items', function() {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();  
    _e('<p class="you-ordered">Hey! ' . $current_user->display_name . 
   ' Here\'s what you ordered:</div></p>'); 
});
```